# Install newer version of sqlite3 on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, sqlite, aws-lambda

I want to use Window functions on sqlite3 on my python3.8 code running on AWS Lambda.
They are available since version `3.25`.

Unfortunately, on AWS Lambda Python3.8, sqlite3 library is outdated:

```py
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
```

while locally, on my homebrew install of Python3.8: (working)

```py
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.31.1'
```

How can I get an sqlite3 version > 3.25 on AWS Lambda Python 3.8 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way: I used the external package `pysqlite3`, in the binary version.

in my requirements.txt

```
pysqlite3-binary==0.4.4
```

in the code

```py
try:
    import pysqlite3 as sqlite3
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import sqlite3  # for local testing because pysqlite3-binary couldn't be installed on macos
```

Comment: Hey Vincent. Please mark your answer as the right one. This is allowed ;)

Comment: Hi Jens, I didn't know but "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". Also, maybe I don't have the best answer... let's check that tomorrow

Comment: It works fine in AWS Lambda. I can confirm that current SQLite3 version in Python 3.9 distribution on AWS Lambda is still '3.7.17' so Windows Function fails with an error like:
"OperationalError: near '(': syntax error".
What I don't get is why current SQLITE3 version (available) is 3.37.0 and the version used in AWS Lambda is 3.7.17

Comment: Somehow for me this does not seem to work, django still complains about the old sqlite3 version. Anything that could have gone wrong?

Comment: Note that `pysqlite3-binary` only has `x86_64` wheels. So it won't install on M1 Macs, etc. I have [solved this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295545/1749551) using `pipenv`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using the new arm64 MacBook Pro, the solution of installing `pysqlite3-binary` is not very feasible for me. I also had to work with a controlled pipeline that only recognizes `Pipfile.lock` but not the `Pipfile` so [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293535/install-newer-version-of-sqlite3-on-aws-lambda-for-use-with-python/73295545#73295545) also doesn't work for me. Instead I found a way to compile `libsqlite3.so.0` from the source code and use it to override the default one on AWS Lambda.

First you want to compile sqlite amalgamation from the source code. I created this `Dockerfile` so we can easily compile for linux/amd64 from arm64 machine:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN yum install -y tar gzip gcc make
ARG SQLITE_VERSION=3430200
RUN curl -sSLO https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-autoconf-${SQLITE_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN tar xf sqlite-autoconf-${SQLITE_VERSION}.tar.gz; \
    mv /sqlite-autoconf-${SQLITE_VERSION} /sqlite-autoconf; \
    cd /sqlite-autoconf; \
    ./configure; \
    make
```

Now we can build the Docker image with command `docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t sqlite3-builder -f Dockerfile .`

The last `make` command will put the `libsqlite3.so.0` under the directory `/sqlite-autoconf/.libs`. We can then use `docker cp` to extract it:

```bash
id=$(docker create sqlite3-builder)
docker cp $id:/sqlite-autoconf/.libs/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 lib/libsqlite3.so.0
docker rm -v $id
```

Now we can upload this `libsqlite3.so.0` file with our other code to AWS Lambda.

The last step is to set an environment variable in AWS Lambda that overrides the system SQLite3. For example, `LD_PRELOAD=/var/task/lib/libsqlite3.so.0`. Note that the `/var/task` (which is value of `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` variable), is default path to your Lambda function code.